# Collect data onto one row using common ID in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
ID   Location1 Location2
AAA  Here      Null
AAA  Null      There
BBB  Here      Null
BBB  Null      There
```

and what I would like is to do is pull everything for each ID onto one line to give the following

```
ID   Location1 Location2
AAA  Here      There
BBB  Here      There
```

I am thinking perhaps I might want to use `groupby` or `transform`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If is possible get first non `Null` values per groups use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.replace('Null', np.nan).groupby('ID', as_index=False).first()
print (df1)
    ID Location1 Location2
0  AAA      Here     There
1  BBB      Here     There
```